# SPFx: How to test for the 3 SharePoint flavors: Classic, New Experience and SPFx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

[image]

When injecting code in the New Experiences (*only possible with Browser Extension*)
I use:

```
    var isClassicSharePoint = typeof SP !== 'undefined';
```

So my generic library knows when to use SP.SOD and other stuff

Now SPFx **does** have a SP object... its just **not** the Classic SP Object

Question:

- What is the most reliable way of determining the 3 versions of SharePoint we now have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for the new webparts, you can look at the context.Environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the this.context.environment.type, which will be a value in the EnvironmentType enumeration, which you can import:

```
import { EnvironmentType } from '@microsoft/sp-client-base';
```

This will have a value of Local, SharePoint, ClassicSharePoint or Test, depending on where the web part is running. You can then test:

```
if (this.context.environment.type === EnvironmentType.Local) { ...
```

Note, if you choose the React starter web part you won't be able to use **this** - you need **this** in the context of the web part class that creates the React component. You can pass the environment or the context through the properties when you create the component.